# Rounded or 'pillowed' emboss for 3d printing

Tags: stl

Sorry I'm starting from absolute zero here, I usually use fusion360 and this is my first attempt with a mesh editor so I'm pretty lost and unfortunately I don't have time to learn all the background I should be starting with.

Anyway...

I have a job where I need to emboss an .svg (provided by the client) onto a 'coin' and 3d print it. Because the geometry was drawn with a pen on a tablet fusion is really struggling with it and I haven't been able to get it to fillet the sharp edges of the extrusion. I'm sure blender can do it but I haven't been able to figure it out.

What I'm doing is making a cylinder for the coin and then importing the .svg on top of that. I can then either convert that to a solid directly or convert the .svg to mesh and then cleanup - degenerate_dissolve to get a clean enough mesh to extrude or convert to solid. From there I can't figure out how to soften or bevel the extrusion. When I try the bevel tool it just explodes it in a crazy way because it's now constructed of so many faces. I would also much prefer a sort of 'pillow' effect to the extrusion rather than a simple bevel on the edges but I have no idea how to get there.

Any pointers? Tools I should look into? I could also pay someone to do it for me if anyone is interested but I would like to learn how.

First pic is what I can get in Fusion360, the second pic is where I'm at in Blender and the 3rd pic is what happens if I try to bevel in blender.
Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Answer (score 0):

For ample control, you could expand on this simple mechanism, with the help of Geometry Nodes:

[image]

Having converted your .svg to a filled 2D curve, you can use a group something like the one above to measure the proximity of your coin's surface to the curve's faces. That proximity can be mapped as you like, to drive the displacement of the coin's surfaces.

This group modifies the svg and creates the coin, but you could work the other way round, or bring the base coin and the svg into a modified dummy object.

Your case may be more elaborate; you may, for instance, distinguish between the coin's sides, or mask out rings between radii, to treat sections of the displacement in different ways: with different heights or curvatures.

[image]

As it would be for any other displacement for use in printing, the mesh will have to be subdivided sufficiently to capture the curvatures of the svg, and the bevel.

[image]